# Android Background Image in XML File

Tags: android, xml, background

I currently have an application which has the default black background for every slide. What I would like to do is alter the XML files to have a background image. I'm assuming there is a simple command for this but haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.

I want an image to the background of my current screen. I don't want the background to ever change, and I would like to put this in my XML file. Here is an example of one of my XML headers...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:weightSum="9"
   android:gravity="center"
    >

...
```

I am assuming there is some simple command such as

```
android:background="file"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `android:background="@drawable/file_name_without_extension"`

If your file is on SD card you can't put it on xml layout.

Answer (score 12):

**android:background = "@drawable/imagename"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background = "@drawable/imagename"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:weightSum="9"
   android:gravity="center"
    >

...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try `android:background = "@drawable/imagename"`

I hope you have an image in your `drawable` folder